# git branch lost in a directory and cannot pull

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a project repository on GitLab. It has two directories **Test** and **Actility**

I have two branches on this project : **master** and **lme-dev**.

When I use the command `git branch` in the folder containing the two directories, it shows :

```
* lme-dev
  master
```

When I use the command `git branch` in the folder **Actility**, it only shows one branch :

```
* master
```

When I use the command `git pull` in the folder **Actility**, it prompts :

> GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found. fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I know I have already committed changes in this folder. On GitLab I can see the directory in the project... How is that possible that for the same project, I have access to one directory and not the other one ?

Comment: Are you using sub-modules?

Comment: do you have a .git folder in Actility as well as in the root folder?

Comment: It sounds to me like something is setup wrong.  Are you using submodules?  Are the permissions correct on the server end?  Does Actility point to the right place?  Git is complaining because it cannot find the server-side repository when you do a git pull.  So either the server-side is broken (you don't have permissions, the project doesn't exist) or the client side is broken in that it's pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: Oh wait, I don't know why I have a .git folder in Actility as well... Should I remove it ? @Richard No, I don't use sub-modules.

Comment: Ok, by moving the .git folder somewhere else I can pull now... Thank you @yorammi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra .git sub-folder in your Actility folder. Just remove it or move it elsewhere outside of the repository.